# Chrome Extension -- Running executeScript in multiple new tabs at the same time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that has a popup.html with a search form.  Like Travelocity or Kayak, the form includes checkboxes so the user can select which sites they want to query.

On submit, `popup.js` launches multiple new tabs based on the selected checkboxes.  In the `tabs.create()` callback for each new tab I use executeScript to:
- (A) inject the user's query into the search form on each of the new pages, and 
- (B) submit the search form on those pages.

My code is working when one checkbox is selected (i.e. new tab is launched), but when multiple new tabs are created simultaneously it appears that the executeScript isn't running consistently.  Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

This leads me to believe that there's some sort of issue with the timing of the script execution, but I'm not sure.

If you have any idea what's going on I'd love to hear your advice.

Also, I'd appreciate any resources on how to debug this sort of issue in the future.

Here's my code on github...

- whole repo: https://github.com/rossmorey/SongSearch
- manifest.json
- popup.html
- popup.js (most relevant file)

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked a more specific question regarding debugging -- I'm familiar with devtools, but in this case I haven't found a way to add a breakpoint to a tab that has just opened.  How would I debug the code inserted by executeScript?  Also, you mention direct URL w/ search params.  Two of the sites I'm querying don't have a URL structure that supports this.  I think you can see in my code, that I use direct URL where possible.  Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like when you open multiple tabs - your popup.html loses the focus and closes, so on tabs.create callbacks which injects your code will not be executed.

Try to create tabs with "active:false" option, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: stringToObj[org], active:false} ...
```

I think it would help you.

And also...
It's a bug in your SeSac inject-code: if no search type defined in popup window, block

```
input[value="undefined"]
```

will not be found, so "checked" property will be called on "undefined" and this will stop you inject script execution.

Comment: Brilliant -- thank you!  That's exactly what the problem was!  In regards to the "undefined" search type issue, input validations are my next feature to implement.  Thanks again. :)

Comment: Nice to help you! Good luck! :)